# Python List Remove Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm getting an error I don't understand, namely, 9 is not being removed from my list:

```
new_list = [4,6,9,8]

for j in new_list:
    if j * 2 >= 10:
        new_list.remove(j)

print new_list

>> [4, 9]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @blhsing you can't mutate a list you are iterating over, as you will get unpredictable results. You can , however, use a list comprehension to construct a new list, e.g.:

```
old_list = [4,6,9,8]
new_list = [j for j in old_list if j*2 < 10]
```

Comment: Well, the results are entirely predictable, and you *can* do it using various approaches (iterating backwards, iterate over indices and take care to adjust the index after mutation, etc).

Comment: I should have been more general, for `list` it maybe predictable. But it is undefined for other data structures and doesn't work for others, like `set` where a `RuntimeError` is generated. [I found a comment by rhettinger that says modifying a `list` iterator is defined but I can't find it in the docs].

Answer (score 0):

You can't mutate the list you're iterating with. Use a copy of it instead:

```
new_list = [4,6,9,8]

for j in new_list[:]:
    if j * 2 >= 10:
        new_list.remove(j)

print new_list
```

This outputs:

```
[4]
```